# HTML5 & CSS3 | Is it semantically correct or not?

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got a question: is it a bad practice to make this lines by css & html code, or it's better just to get this lines from .psd layout and just paste it in html as a picture? 
 Thank you for your attention!

Here is some pics:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'd be far better off just making a vertical image in my opinion. Though your question is rather subjective and there's no real 'answer'.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically it depends on your needs: If you need to change colors frequently it's more efficient to use html than always have to create a new image file...if it's an one time modification, image is enough. But technically by code is a better option because you save bandwidth and processing from your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

In a world of increasing resolution, it's a good idea to avoid images if you can.

Using HTML/CSS or SVG guarantees perfect results regardless of the resolution of the viewer's device.

Using an image guarantees that somewhere, sometime, someone will display it in a way that makes it look blurry and poor quality.